# How to check who update the working copy folder in tortoise svn?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I can see revision log (for commits) but i can't see update log in a repository working copy folder.

I try to find it in documentation but have no results.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Not getting your question. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: using tortoise svn you able to see any revision log (commit,edit,add,etc) in a repository, but how if we want to see who just update our working copy folder on our pc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're the only one who should be updating your working copy. As for seeing where your working copy is relative to the repository, `svn info` will give you the revision of your working copy (among other things) and you can compare that to the revision log to see if you're behind and by how much.

It is not advised to have multiple developers using the same working copy. File ownership becomes an issue, and there's a significant chance of corruption and/or lost changes from simultaneous attempts to change the same file (eg. developer A begins editing a file, developer B edits that same file and commits his changes, developer A saves his file *without* B's changes and commits, developer B's work has now been lost).

Comment: interesting... we have a web server that have 2 folder locations, production and testing, and we have to managed it manually especially on updating the folder, and there are 5 server administrator, and we want to trace it. so basicly its not in working copy but in server copy.

Comment: I'd advise separating deployment to the server from the repository. Subversion isn't designed to do what you want to do, you need a release management tool (and probably a provisioning tool like Puppet or Chef).